# Crear select para un formulario con datos de una db (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, laravel, axios, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

Seré lo mas conciso posible hasta donde llegue mi entendimiento.

Estoy haciendo un formulario en `laravel8x/jetstream` y necesito agregar nuevos artículos a un menú de ventas, el mismo tiene una restricción de llave foránea con lo que son las categorías y me imaginé que si reutilizo los datos de la tabla `categories` seria menos complejo.

Intente esta forma (claro es basica):

```
<form action="">
    <div class="grid">
        <label for="name" class="forma-label ">nombre:</label>
        <input type="text"  id="name" placeholder="Nuevo artículo" class="forma-input text-md">

        <label class="forma-label text-md"id="description" >descripción del artículo:</label>
        <textarea type="text" rows="3" id="description" placeholder="descripcion del articulo" class="forma-input ">ingrese la descripción</textarea>

        <label for="price" class="forma-label text-md">precio en $</label>
        <input type="text" id="price" class="forma-input" placeholder="precio">

        <label for="categories" class=>seleccione una categoría</label>
        <select name="" id="">
            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <option value="$category->id">{{$category->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <select name="" id=""></select>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Acá está el método desde donde envío la variable de la bd:

```
<?php
class MenuComponent extends Component
{

    public function render()
    { 
        $categories = Category::all();
        $menus= Menu::all();

        return view('livewire.menu-component', compact('menus', 'categories'));
    }
}
```

Es un componente `livewire` utilizado como controlador.

Me da un error de que la variable `$categorias` no esta definida.
le he preguntado a un amigo y el me recomendó que cree una api y que la consuma con `axios` (esto de crear api y consumirla  no lo he entendido nada) he visto este tutorial en el que medio entendí [Tutorial](https://www.nigmacode.com/laravel/crear-api-rest-con-laravel/)

Alguien puede decirme si estoy yendo por el camino correcto para hacer el `select` o hay otra manera mas sencilla y hacer que las categorías sean dinámicas, cosa que se puedan actualizar por favor, de verdad, tengo varios días buscando en internet y solo veo tutoriales para `VueJS` con inertia y estoy usando `laravel 8.x jetstream`, `livewire` y `alpinejs`
y ya me hice una ensalada con el código probando cosas a lo loco...

De ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: Agrega el método desde el cual envías la variable `$categories` a dicha vista

Comment: alli esta editada la pregunta ya tiene el metodo compact y me arroja un error otra cosa no coloque los use namespaces xq se pierde el formato de codigo es un componente de livewire utilizado como controlador

Comment: El código que expones es correcto y funcional, igual puedes tratar como: `["categories" => Category::all, "menus" => Menu::all() ]`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta manera ya que no hace falta decir compact y además te falta indicar el nombre que le das a la variable en la vista y el nombre de la variable en el controlador.

```php
public function render()
{

    $categories = Category::all();
    $menus= Menu::all();
    return view('livewire.menu-component', ['menus' => $menus, 'categories ' => $categories]);
}
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con el nombre del controlador?

Comment: Me refiero al nombre de la variable en el controlador

Comment: Puede ser que el op no use controladores, con livewire se vuelven opcionales